# Finding recurrence relation for digits

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science, generating-functions

codes have been generated odd number of odd digits. Let $ a_n $ be the number of valid n-digit activation codes. Find the recurrence relation.

I can't figure out and understand the question. Can you give me some hints ?

Comment: I would think of it along the following lines: how can we generate a valid $n$-digit code? Either take an _invalid_ $(n - 1)$-digit code and append an odd digit to it, or take a _valid_ $(n - 1)$-digit code and append an even digit to it.

Comment: It looks like $a_n$ is the number of integers in the range $[0,10^n-1]$ whose sum of digits is odd. (It doesn't matter much whether you drop leading digits $0$ or not, as long as each integer is counted just once.) Maybe this makes it more clear? Also it looks like you don't really need any recurrence relation to find $a_n$, but you can if you must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can we generate a valid $n$-digit code? We can either

1. Take a *valid* $(n - 1)$-digit code and append an even digit to it. Since there are $5$ ways to choose an even digit, this can be done in $5 \cdot a_{n - 1}$ ways.
2. Take an *invalid* $(n - 1)$-digit code and append an odd digit to it. Observe that the number of invalid codes of length $n - 1$ is $10^{n - 1} - a_{n - 1}$. Since there are $5$ ways to choose an odd digit, this can be done in $5 \cdot (10^{n - 1} - a_{n - 1})$ ways.

In total, we get:
$$
a_n = \underbrace{5 \cdot a_{n - 1}}_{\text{case 1}} + \underbrace{5 \cdot (10^{n - 1} - a_{n - 1})}_{\text{case 2}} = 5 \cdot 10^{n - 1}
$$